# Getting error with a non-promise function inside a promise chain

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

In third-party made codebase I found this promise chain:

```
const signUp = ({ dispatch, commit, getters }, payload) => {
  return dispatch('startTask', { id: signUpRequestTaskId }, { root: true })
    .then(() => enrichSignUpPayload(payload, getters))
    .then(apiRequest.signUpB2b);
};
```

For solving a certain issue in the app, I need to remove the first link of the chain (`dispatch('startTask',...root: true })`):

```
const signUp = ({ dispatch, commit, getters }, payload) => {
  return enrichSignUpPayload(payload, getters)
    .then(apiRequest.signUpB2b);
};
```

However this triggers the following error:

> enrichSignUpPayload(...).then is not a function

Why? There was no error before I remove the first link so why the second link becomes a problem now? I don't get it.

Here's the body of the `enrichSignUpPayload()` function just in case:

```
const enrichSignUpPayload = payload => pipe(
  payload,
  (p) => ({ ...p, fromApp: isFromApp() }),
  aperoFromStorage
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because `enrichSignUpPayload` does not return a `promise` as `dispatch` does. Also, the first version of `signUp` works because a call to `promise.then` also returns a `promise`, so that we can call the next `.then` on it. Refer to [this](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) for more info about it.

I assume, to make things work you could do something like:

```
const enrichSignUpPayload = payload => pipe(
  payload,
  (p) => ({ ...p, fromApp: isFromApp() }),
  aperoFromStorage,
  (possibleValueFromAperoFromStorage) => Promise.resolve(possibleValueFromAperoFromStorage)
);
```

Or if the `enrichSignUpPayload` is not async you can just simply do:

```
const signUp = ({ dispatch, commit, getters }, payload) => {
  const result = enrichSignUpPayload(payload, getters);
  return apiRequest.signUpB2b(result)
};
```

Comment: First solution works thanks a lot, however the second one looks much better. For some reason though, when I do this the promise chain seems to resolve instantly without going through all its links. Any idea why?

Comment: as mentioned in the answer, `enrichSignUpPayload` should be synchronous to make second solution work properly

Comment: As far as I can tell it is synchronous, can't see any asynchronous API call in `aperoFromStorage` and `isFromApp()` is definitely synchronous too.

Comment: Hm, it should work then.. what promise chain are you talking about? See no chain in second solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a function to return

```
const signUp = ({ dispatch, commit, getters }, payload) => {
  return () => enrichSignUpPayload(payload, getters) // Here add function
    .then(apiRequest.signUpB2b);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`enrichSignUpPayload` is not returning a promise.

You can wrap the result using [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

```
const signUp = ({ dispatch, commit, getters }, payload) =>
    Promise.resolve(enrichSignUpPayload(payload, getters))
        .then(apiRequest.signUpB2b)
```

Comment: Applying first solution of @streletss works, but his second solution just like yours seems to instantly make the chain resolve without going through all steps. Any idea why?